# VueJS adding variable to complex style class

Tags: css, vuejs3, styling

I am trying to add a variable to a particular style, I have tried the traditional method of injecting it through computed but it didn't work.

Here is the html:

```
            <div class="progress-card">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="percent">
                    <svg class="my_svg">
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                        <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="num">
                        <h2>90<span>%</span></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="text">Html</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the style:

```
<style>
.progress-card:nth-child(2) svg.my_svg circle:nth-child(2)
{
  stroke-dashoffset:calc(440 - (440 * 50) / 100);
  stroke:#00ff43;
}

</style>
```

This is the only part of the style that needs to be a variable
I can't adapt this most likely because of ":nth-child" and "calc".

I am supposed to make the value of "50" a variable

This would be easy if I could insert this to style directly but I can't.

Comment: I solved this by making these an inline style. adn using the :style declaration.

Comment: Great. Please show us your solution and mark your answer with solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using inline styling as shown below.

```
<svg class="my_svg">
    <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="70"></circle>
    <circle :style="`
            stroke-dashoffset: calc(440 - (440 * ${timeRem*100/timeGiven}) / 100);
            stroke: ${ (timeRem*100/timeGiven) < 25 ? '#cc0000' : '#00ff43'};`"
        cx="70" cy="70" r="70">
    </circle>
</svg>
```